# nano unhighlight string if a quote is escaped

Tags: regular-expression, gnu, nano, syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to unhighlight string if one of the quotes is escaped.

`sh.nanorc` regex is as follows:
`color brightyellow ""(\\.|[^"])*""`

I'm having success with the closing quote when preceding it with `[^\\]`:
`color brightyellow ""(\\.|[^"])*"[^\\]"`

But if I do the same to the opening one, although it does the work, but it also starts either coloring any other symbol preceding the string if the opening quote isn't escaped, or uncoloring the string if it starts at beginning of line.

So, how to get it done clean with both quotes?

Answer (score 0):

The optimal way to do it would be with a negative [lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind). But since nano uses POSIX ERE (Extended Regular Expressions) regex engine, it's not possible to do it with a single regex. Workarounds are needed and they're not perfect.

You can utilize the fact that color changes are applied from the top to bottom. So, first, use your old regex. Then, below it, use the same regex but with `\\` (escaped backslash) before the starting and closing quotes. Assign default color to it.

E.g.:

```
color brightyellow ""[^"]*""
color white "\\"[^"]*\\""
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, it doesn't work all well. With a tweak like so: `"(\\"[^"]*")|("[^"]*\\")"`, it could catch either escape separately, but the problem of a positive consecutive regex is that it remains forever instead of being absorbed by a preceding regex that is revealed with the new condition in effect. Which highlights `"string1\"string2"` all white instead of all brightyellow.